# Fetching Ubuntu's OpenPGP keys for verification fails with "not a key ID: skipping"

Tags: gnupg, keyrings, cd-image, openpgp, keyserver

I have entered this request into the "Terminal" program, per [this documentation](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/how-to-verify)

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys "8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374 2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092" "C598 6B4F 1257 FFA8 6632 CBA7 4618 1433 FBB7 5451"
```

and received the expected responses:

```
gpg: directory /home/ubuntu/.gnupg' created
gpg: new configuration file `/home/ubuntu/.gnupg/gpg.conf' created
gpg: WARNING: options in `/home/ubuntu/.gnupg/gpg.conf' are not yet active during this run
gpg: keyring `/home/ubuntu/.gnupg/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/home/ubuntu/.gnupg/pubring.gpg' created
```

but the response to

```
gpg: requesting key EFE21092 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
```

was:

```
gpg: "8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374 2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092" not a key ID: skipping
gpg: "C598 6B4F 1257 FFA8 6632 CBA7 4618 1433 FBB7 5451" not a key ID: skipping
```

The "trustdb" was not created, the "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) " was not imported, the "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key " was not imported.

Answer (score 8):

This seems to be same issue others had with GnuPG on Windows and Mac OS X, reported on [Super User in the question "gpg2 not a key id: skipping” when trying to download public keys"](https://superuser.com/q/1071045/102155):

> While the command works fine under GnuPG on Linux, it fails in
>   Windows. I've been able to make it work by removing all spaces:
>
> ```
> gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 843938DF228D22F7B3742BC0D94AA3F0EFE21092
> ```
>
> C5986B4F1257FFA86632CBA746181433FBB75451
>
> (the quotes are not required any more, either; so I removed them).
>
> If you really want to verify against signatures from Ubuntu, you
>   obviously shouldn't copy/paste this specific command line as is, but
>   remove the space from the original Ubuntu page on your own.

The solution will be the same, and you should get the command running by removing the spaces in the fingerprints (the hexadecimal numbers).