# Why does ubuntu download verification require 2 keys, and why do I only have 1?

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, downloads, gnupg, keyserver

I am following instructions [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#4-retrieve-the-correct-signature-key) and I am only seeing terminal output for one missing key:

```bsh
$ gpg --keyid-format long --verify ubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64.SHA256SUMS.gpg ubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64.SHA256SUMS
gpg: Signature made to 26. august 2021 09.52.49 UTC
gpg:                using RSA key 843938DF228D22F7B3742BC0D94AA3F0EFE21092
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

However in the instructions, as well as in this question [Fetching Ubuntu's OpenPGP keys for verification fails with "not a key ID: skipping"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/796271/fetching-ubuntus-openpgp-keys-for-verification-fails-with-not-a-key-id-skippi)

there are two:

```
gpg: Signature made Thu Apr  5 22:19:36 2018 EDT
                    using DSA key ID 46181433FBB75451
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
gpg: Signature made Thu Apr  5 22:19:36 2018 EDT
                    using RSA key ID D94AA3F0EFE21092
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

Can someone tell me why there are two, and why I am only seeing one?

Side note:
gpg's `--keyid-format` flag doesn't seem to do anything (I am just getting the fingerprint rather then ID in the output as if this flag is not there).

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that you do not currently have the Ubuntu CD signing public keys in your GPG Keyring. The instructions on the page you linked-to include steps for importing the key in such situations:

```
gpg --keyid-format long --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0x46181433FBB75451 0xD94AA3F0EFE21092
```

This will download the key and add it into your GPG Keyring ready for use. From there you will be able to re-run the first command again, and it should succeed:

```
gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS
```